# routes REST redirection is not working properly in Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have added new resources to my application.

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Rake routes for the same is also showing correct redirection paths.

```
rake routes CONTROLLER=posts

   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
```

But when i use following lines of code :

```
<%= link_to 'Get Complete Blog List', posts_path %>
```

t's throwing error :

```
undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0xb464058c>:0xb4e8a274>
```

Comment: `#<#<` seems very strange there's possible not routes mistake.

Comment: I too wonder the same. It's quite unusual behavior with rails routes.

Comment: Could you check mistakes in all files which you've created before. I guess there's typo.

Comment: Where do you call posts_path ? If you call it outside of the view in some class you have to delegate it to the view object.

Comment: I am calling it in the View page, in _header partial where I have the 'Get Complete Blog List' link.